# React : Best way to put dummy content in a component

Tags: reactjs

I want to prepare my component to receive an JSON object from the backend.
So in my main component, I've got a state :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       contributions : {
         [
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '1',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test2',
            value: '12',
          },
         ]
    }

render() {
    const { contributions } = this.state;
    return (
         <MyComponent contributions={contributions} />        
    );
  }
```

So now, I want to know the best solution to render my object in MyComponent so I can have for output :

```
<div>
   <span class="name">Test</span>
   <span class="value">1</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class="name">Test2</span>
   <span class="value">12</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing you are saving to your state is not JSON, Json objects are key value pairs.

Comment: can you explain what the data model you get from the server is? and where does it get stored? is it state in this class for the api response or is it props that come in from some storage? also your current state implementation is invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON objects are key-value pairs. So if you're saving the JSON to your state, it can look something like

```
this.state = {
   contributions : {
     "nameValuePairs":[
      {
        "name": 'Test',
        "value": '1',
      },
      {
        "name": 'Test2',
        "value": '12',
      },
     ]
}
```

Now to map through the objects you can do something like 
`{this.state.contributions.nameValuePairs.map((item)=>(<TestChild item={item}/>))`

Bascially your parent would look something like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TestChild from './TestChild'
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         contributions : {
           "nameValuePairs":[
            {
              "name": 'Test',
              "value": '1',
            },
            {
              "name": 'Test2',
              "value": '12',
            },
           ]
      }
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.contributions.nameValuePairs.map((item)=>(<TestChild item={item}/>))}
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

and your child component can have inside it, something like

```
render () {
 return (
   <div>{this.props.item.name}</div>
   <div>{this.props.item.value}</div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

MyComponent

```
<div>
   <span class="name">{this.props.name}</span>
   <span class="value">{this.props.value}</span>
</div>
```

ParentComponent

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       contributions : {
         [
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '1',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test2',
            value: '12',
          },
         ]
    }

render() {
    const { contributions } = this.state;
    return (
        contributions && contributions.length && contributions.map(contrib => (
            <MyComponent {...contrib) />        
        ))
    );
  }
```